# Why does 'u0'=30000 in C?

Tags: c

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d %c",'u0','u0');
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it on my machine, the output is "30000 0", and I have never seen 'u0' used to represent a character (or maybe an integer in fact). 
Perhaps this implies that the character/integer is unsigned?

Comment: No, it only implies multiple character constants exhibit either undefined or implementation-defined behavior (depending on your compiler, and maybe the version of C used). Repeat your experiment with a hex output, and compare to an ASCII table to see *why* '30000'.

Comment: Search "multibyte character literal".

Comment: @Jongware So 'u0' is just 30000 for short and should be avoided for it's unportable?

Answer (score 5):

That's a multi-character constant. It has type `int` and an implementation-defined value.

Quoting the latest draft of the C standard ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), section 6.4.4.4 paragraph 10:

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one
>   character (e.g.,
>   **`'ab'`**), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is
>   implementation-defined.

As for why it has the specific value `30000`, apparently your compiler gives the constant `'u0'` the value `'u' << 8 + '0'`. Since `'u'==117` and `'0'==48` (in an ASCII-based character set), the result is `30000`. But don't count on that specific value; it could vary for other compilers.

I advise not using such constants.